# Invoke outlook from javascript & send mail automatically

Tags: javascript, outlook

I have a scenario if the user clicks submit button mail should be sent automatically through outlook without POP-UP(asking for us to click send button).
How to do this & is der anyway to access outlook api for auto sending a mail.

Comment: i think this is a very bad idea, if there were a method to send a mail from the pc of your visitors it could be used for spam and other bad things. maybe you can send the mail server side to the desired recipients and in CC to the sender (which will enter her email in the submission form)?

Answer (score 0):

There is, but not using Javascript. Outlook has a COM interface (and probably .NET as well) which allows sending e-mails, but it will show warnings as well. The only way is to actuall build an Outlook add-in that can send e-mails 'from the inside'.

To help you build this, you can use [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm), which provides Outlook-like functions that can be called without the warnings. But as far as I know, there's no way to control Outlook from outside to send mail and especially not from Javascript.

This measure is taken to prevent malicious scripts sending spam using your Outlook.